# Make reconnect Openwrt script to run in boot and keep checking for current status

Tags: bash, while-loop, openwrt

I have this that is working pretty good in openwrt:

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x #debug
while true; do
  wget -O /tmp/extip 'http://ifconfig.me/ip' 2>/dev/null
  EXT_IP=$(cat /tmp/extip)
  INT_IP="$(ip addr show dev wwan0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)"
  ROOTER=/usr/lib/rooter
  [ -z $EXT_IP ] && continue
  if [ $(echo "$INT_IP" | grep "$EXT_IP" -q; echo $?) -eq 1 ]; then
    /sbin/ifup wan1
    $ROOTER/pwrtoggle.sh 1
    echo "NAT-DETECT: External ($EXT_IP) does not match Internal ($INT_IP); Reconnecting WAN1..." > /dev/kmsg
    /etc/init.d/firewall restart
    /etc/init.d/miniupnpd restart
  fi
  sleep 30
done
#set +x #debug
```

How do I make this script run in the boot (or after sometime) and let it running in background forever checking current IP status and doing its job? Also it looks like it's not good to have a init script with "sleep", because it's considered bad form. What would be an optimized form of this script to match my purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed GNU screen on my OpenWRT and in `/etc/rc.local` I have something like this:

```
# start screen in detached mode
screen -dm -S boot -c /dev/null bash /root/bin/monitor.sh
```

It will run in background. You can also attach to it with `screen -r boot` after login.

You can try if it works for you.

Comment: Great idea. Instead of using screen I've installed tmux since I'm more used to it. Thanks!

In my case my rc.local is now: `sleep 120
tmux new-session -d -s "natdetector" /root/connect.sh
exit 0`